# Adding Duration in dateTimePicker

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two DateTimePickers one as Start Time and other one as end time.
I also have a text box that has duration.

I would like to know how can I add the duration to start time datetimePicker to automatically get the end time in the endTime dateTimePicker?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though I believe your `Service Duration` is a `combobox`, I've still used `textbox` as per your question.

Call `textchanged`. When text in textbox changes, the time is added to `dateTimePicker2`

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mins = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(mins);
}
```

For combobox, call `textchanged` as well.

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox1.Text == null)
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }

    else if (comboBox1.Text == "15")
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(15);
    }

    else if (comboBox1.Text == "30")
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(30);
    }

    else if (comboBox1.Text == "60")
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right it is a comboBox my mistake. I did implement your answer but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. Heir is how I did it:   private void cmbDuration_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbDuration.SelectedIndex == -1 || cmbDuration.Text == null)
            {
                dtpEntry1.Value = dtpEntry.Value;
            }

Comment: if (cmbDuration.Text == "15")
            {
                dtpEntry1.Value = dtpEntry.Value.AddMinutes(15);
            }
            else if(cmbDuration.Text == "30")
            {
                dtpEntry1.Value = dtpEntry.Value.AddMinutes(30);
            }

            else if (cmbDuration.Text == "60")
            {
                dtpEntry1.Value = dtpEntry.Value.AddMinutes(60);
            }
        }

Comment: My duration comboBox is generated by the ServiceType comboBox. As in the duration is determined by the service type you chose. should I tried putting the code on the serviceType comboBox_TextChanged?

Comment: Even when I put on serviceType comboBox_TextChanged still doesn't work and no error is Showing